# Como guardar los datos de un tags?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy realizando una practica, no encuentro como tomar los valores para luego enviarlos por ajax al controlador, estoy trabajando con C# MVC, tengo estos tags [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]ahora lo que quiero es guardar esos tags en una variable pero no hayo como; [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] esto es lo demas [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos kevin, para poder ayudarte por favor haz click en el elemento donde estan los actores y dale inspeccionar elemento para saber que elemento html utiliza.

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que aunque tenga esa apariencia, estará hecho en un campo de texto en el que simplemente con js modificas la apariencia y le vas metiendo esos estilos, ¿no? Si es así, que lo que tienes es un string de palabras separadas por comas, yo lo que miraría es de coger el valor del input con js tal y como tienes arriba, hacer un split (separar un string en partes) separandolo por comas, y ahí ya tendrías un array con cada palabra. No sé si es exactamente lo que estás buscando.

Un saludo.

Comment: Como lo dices, es un campo de texto, editorfor de razor, y lo que quiero hacer es lo que dices, tomar esos valores, lo que sucede es que no toma ningún valor cuando lo quiero hacer js y no sé cual es la razón.

Comment: ¿Me podrías compartir el código HTML por favor? Sin verlo es complicado saber si el código JS está correcto.